# enhanced for loop (java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

how can i change out the for loop in this program:

```
   public class deleteplz{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] cdSporNavn = new String[4];
    cdSporNavn[0]="fritjof i fjøset";
    cdSporNavn[1]="java jive";
    cdSporNavn[2]="hæla i taket";
    cdSporNavn[3]=cdSporNavn[1] + "på julebord";

    for (int sporNr=0; sporNr<cdSporNavn.length; sporNr++){
      if(cdSporNavn[sporNr].indexOf("java") != -1){
        System.out.println(cdSporNavn[sporNr]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the enhanced for loop? thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Whats an 'enhanced for loop'?  Do you mean for in?

Comment: Its called a for-in loop :) There is no such thing as an enhanced for-loop.

Comment: @olive [You're very wrong.](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Comment: Clash of languages, i'm coming from JS background, @SotiriosDelimanolis to me you are wrong :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @olive_tree then you should refrain yourself from relating Java terminology with that of JavaScript because there is a term called enhanced for-loop and it exists even in the Java docs. Moreover, the question uses a Java tag and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using syntax like the following:

```
for (String s: cdSporNavn){
  if(s.indexOf("java") != -1){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

See [Using Enhanced For-Loops with Your Classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) for further information and examples.